# Call quick fix programmatically in an ordinary Java application

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a folder contains a java application. The application contains java compiler errors which I extract them using below code.

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, files);

DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, Arrays.asList(javaFileObject));
boolean sucess = task.call();
```

I then can extract more details information about compiler errors using below code.

```
for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) 
    if (diagnostic.getKind().name().equals("ERROR")) 
       System.out.format("Error on line %d in %s%n", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), ((FileObject) diagnostic.getSource()).toUri());
```

However, I would like to **programmatically** fix the detected compiler errors. I need to programmatically call an API like **Eclipse Quick Fix** to fix the compiler error. Note that my program is an ordinary java application and not a plugin, and the source code contains compiler error is an external folder.

Please let me know if there is any api that I can programmatically call quick fix based on the detected compiler errors.

Comment: This is MUCH too broad for SO.  You are asking for an AI system that can parse the errors, then make an intelligent choice among the multiple options potentially offered by Eclipse's "Quick Fix" option.

Comment: I think if someone actually developed this they would be a billionaire within the week.

Comment: I want a program to suggest me some possibilities to fix bugs. At the moment eclipse quick fix can do. But, I am not sure if I can call that in an ordinary java application.

Comment: When you fix the errors manually in Eclipse, for what percentage of them is the first suggested fix the right choice? Remember that a wrong fix converts a compiler error to wrong code, making things worse.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, if I can have around 50% a correct suggestion, then it is a lot for me. Actually, my program tries to fix compiler errors automatically, and using quick fix I want to reduce search space for my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Eclipse IDE plugin which defines an Eclipse [`application`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fproduct_def_extpt.htm) that you can invoke from command-line.

Then in this application, you can import the project in the workspace -according to command-line parameters most likely-, run a `project.build(...)` command to produce the error markers, iterate on those markers provided by `project.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE)` and invoke on each of this markers `IDE.getMarkerHelpRegistry().getResolutions(marker)`. The marker resolutions can then be invoked with the [`run` method on IMarkerResolution](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIMarkerResolution.html&anchor=run-org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker-). Note that there is no guarantee that 1. the marker resolution works without human interaction 2. the result is better than showing the error.